# Laravel 5.4 Named Error Bag during registration failure

Tags: php, forms, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

Using Laravel's built in Authentication (`php artisan make:auth`) I'm displaying both the registration and login form on the same page.  However, because both forms have the same fields (email and password), the error for one form is also shown on the other - ie when you register with an email that's taken, or login with an incorrect email.

I've changed the named error bag (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#named-error-bags) for the login form, by copying `sendFailedLoginResponse` from `AuthenticatesUsers.php` to my `LoginController.php`, and changing:

`->withErrors($errors);`

to

`->withErrors($errors, 'login');`

And also changing my login blade error output from:

`$errors->has()`

to

`$errors->login->has()`

However, I'm trying to change the named error bag for the validation failure during registration, but struggling to find where or how I can do this.  It seems that a failed registration never makes it past the following in `RegistersUsers.php`, but I can't track down what / where I can extend and add `withErrors`:

`$this->validator($request->all())->validate();`

I understand there is another way to do this, by setting `protected $errorBag = 'register';` somewhere, but I can't work out where.

Any help would be appreciated, as I've only just started to use Laravel.

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the forms?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with the register function, and i ended up overwriting the register function in my `registerController` and placed a try catch to `$this->validator($request->all())->validate`. So now it looks like

```
try {
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
} catch (ValidationException $e) {
    $e->errorBag('register');

    throw $e;
}
```

and it seems to work like a charm!
(I was working in laravel 5.6 but i'm sure it'll work in laravel 5.4)