# Laravel 8 Named error bag during registration

Tags: php, laravel

*Before you mark this question as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069028/laravel-5-4-named-error-bag-during-registration-failure), first understand that this question is based on Laravel 8 while the former is on Laravel 5.4 which handle the auth differently.*

I would like to add a named error bag on laravel validation during registration. I am using the default laravel auth

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

Below is the class that handles registration.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
   

    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }
    
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Registration is handled by **register** method in the above class. Laravel has hidden this method and imports it to the above class using the **use RegistersUsers;** declaration.

[image]

To add a named error bag as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#named-error-bags), I need to access this hidden **register** method. How do I do it.

I know that one way of doing this is by writing my own register method, but is there an alternative?

I need to add a named error bag because my login and register forms are in the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the validator to named error bag, so it can be achieved by overriding register method from RegisterUsers trait:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return redirect('register')->withErrors($validator, 'login');
}
```

Or you can validate it with an error name bag

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all())->validateWithBag('login');

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return redirect('register');
}
```